# Is there any possible vulnerabilities in my coding?

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment and we had to create a basic program that accepted three strings and then reversed the string. We were also asked to find possible vulnerabilities within the code, however, I am not finding any. Any tips or suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string reverse(string s) {
string result;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
result += s[s.length() - i - 1];
}
return result;
}

int main() {
string s;
cout << "Welcome to the String Reversal Program\n";
cout << "Enter First Word: ";
getline(cin, s);
cout << "Reverse of \"" << s << "\" is \"" << reverse(s) << "\"" << endl;

cout << "\nEnter Second Word: ";
getline(cin, s);
cout << "Reverse of \"" << s << "\" is \"" << reverse(s) << "\"" << endl;

cout << "\nEnter Third Word: ";
getline(cin, s);
cout << "Reverse of \"" << s << "\" is \"" << reverse(s) << "\"" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is your assignment to write your own code and analyse it for vulnerabilities, or were you given a program that does it, and asked to analyse it for vulnerabilities? The former does not really make much sense.

Comment: Passing a string longer than 2gb would cause UB, due to `i` having a wrong type. Should've been `size_t`.

Comment: <https://codereview.stackexchange.com/>

Comment: A good compiler should have [warned you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02b67b34957805d6) about using the wrong variable type for `i` in the `for` loop.  Maybe the first step is to turn on all warnings for your compiler, compile the code yourself, and address all the warnings.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm sure the kernel will fail to allocate any contiguous space due to fragmentation long before 2Gb anyway.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - The assignment was to create a program and then analyze it for vulnerabilities, my apologies if that was not clear.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie With `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` both gcc and clang will complain about signed vs unsigned int. However they will not complain about 32-bit unsigned vs 64 bit unsigned.

Comment: @Jellyboy Has only be contiguous in virtual address space, right? Which doesn't sound hard, unlike contiguity in physical space.

Comment: `getline(cin, s);` <- DOS attack. Depending on the source of your input, an atacker could sent an extremely long string to fill up your memory.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I guess you are right. I'm testing with 12G file size and it's passing.

Comment: @Jellyboy Just remove the variable and the loop [altogether](https://godbolt.org/z/EEaaWdj87), so you don't have to worry about those details.

Comment: @Bob__ true but the point is analyzing his code as is, not refactor it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for an open-ended review of code.

Answer (score 1):

Accordding to Cyber Security Terms

- The vulnerability is a potential overflow for the string size or an out of bounds error resulting of the signed / unsigned comparison
- The Asset is the functionality to create reverse string
- The violated Cyber Security Attribute (based on CIA) is A, Availability
- The resulting Damage Scenario is complete loss of functionality and potential side effects on other code running in the same unprotected core
- The Thread or Damage impact regarding SFOP, is "High" for the Operational part. Others cannot be judged, because the Operational Environment and the Intented Functionality are unknown
- The Thread Scenario accoding to STRIDE is D, Denial of Service
- The Attack Path is input of long strings
- The Attack Feasibility rating according to ET, SE, KoIC, WoE, EQ is High.
- The overall Risk Level is High
- The resulting Risk Treatment Decision is: Mitigate

**So, fix the bug.**

Additionally, the code violates all Coding guidelines like CERT or NIS rules. It will also not pass any reasonable SAST or DAST tools. Also normal static code anaylsis tools like Coverity, QAC, SonarCube or Polyspace will find the problem.

But also any reasonable compiler will emit a warning for the signed / unsigned comparison

Welcome to CS....

Comment: That was one of the best c++ answers I've seen in a while. Congrats!